# How obtain TTL(Time To Live) in DNS?

Tags: c#, dns, ttl

I want to monitor the DNS address. I need to get the `TTL` (time to live) which tells me when the DNS record will expire.

How do I obtain the TTL in C#??

Answer (score 3):

There is .Net sample code at [C# .NET DNS query component](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12072/C-NET-DNS-query-component) that appears to provide the API you require.